# How to clone private Git repository in EC2 instance

Tags: git, bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I have a **lambda** function which starts an EC2 instance. I specify in the `boto3` call the `user_data` some `bash` script which install dependencies and start services.

I would like to clone a private Bitbucket repository at that time, so my question is...

What is the best practice in this case?

I am thinking about download some ssh keys from S3 and configure everything with the `user_data` script but I think is not a good practice.

Suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I wouldn't recommend putting ssh keys in S3. If someone accidentally exposes the bucket, you are compromised. Instead, generate ssh-keys (through user data) and upload the key to Git using their API. Use `https://api.github.com/user/keys` Github API

Comment: @KrishnaKumarR you are recommending generating a new SSH key and uploading it to Bitbucket every single time an EC2 instance is launched?

Comment: That is, so many keys. That lambda function is going to be called several times per day.

Comment: An SSH key is just a big string value. You need to determine a location you feel is secure enough and store it there. I recommend looking into EC2 Systems Manager Parameter Store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I managed the SSH key inside a S3 bucket and provision that key with the following code in the `user_data` script:

```
aws s3 cp s3://<bucket_name>/resources/id_rsa id_rsa --region <your_region>
chmod 600 id_rsa
mkdir -p /root/.ssh
ssh-keyscan -t rsa <your_domain> > /root/.ssh/known_hosts
mv id_rsa /root/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Of course that bucket is protected in order to avoid an accidental exposure of the key.